# Hiding a link with Angular routing

Tags: angular

I want to hide a link with Angular routing.
I want to implement somthing like

```
a [routerLink]="['/Brand']" [routerLinkActive]="['tt'] *ngif="cartypepermission==1">Car Brands</a>
```

where the `*ngIf` defines if the link shows or not.
This does not work I get a runtime error:

```
Unexpected closing tag "a". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's `<a`, not `a`. And it's `*ngIf`, not `*ngif`.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks
Worked for me the capital I.
The < was missing because I don't know how to tell this platform that this is a code and it took it as an HTML.
Moshik